# What impact has source order on accessibility? Does source order matters?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics, wai-aria

In one of my projects my live would be much easier if I could place the HTML markup for the main navigation menu (including ARIA roles) just before the page's footer.

Would this have a negative impact on accessibility for screen-readers and the like? Or does source order actually matters at all as long the correct elements are used?

Answer (score 5):

Source order does make a difference, screen readers generally progress in source order. However, consistency, useful skip links and headings make more difference.

This is a good article on doing skip links (when the nav is below the content):
http://www.nomensa.com/blog/2004/what-are-skip-links/

Also, have a look at WAI-ARIA landmarks as another (supplementary) method:
http://www.nomensa.com/blog/2011/how-aria-landmark-roles-help-screen-reader-users/

NB: You do still need skip links, as visual keyboard users have no access to landmarks.

Answer (score -1):

There are some «good practice» that tell us to put navigation to where the most of people expect it to be. In most cases it is on the top or on sidebar. The source order doesn't matter until your page is easy to work with. Only A/B test can give  you a clear understanding of navigation placements impact.